# Unable to navigate to jsp page through filter

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, session, filter

I have an spring/hibernate based application which can be logged in into through two other applications.

I am trying to implement session timeout in my application using filter.
Filter code

```
if (session != null && session.getAttribute("user")!=null) {            
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        } else {
            req.getRequestDispatcher("http://localhost:8080/Competitor-X-Ref-SearchResults/views/cross_reference_timeout.jsp").forward(req,
                    res);           
        }
```

But the application is not navigating to the URL mentioned in code. On going through logs I can see following lines:

> WARN    2017-02-01 11:51:45,619 [http-bio-8080-exec-10]
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound  - No mapping found for
>   HTTP request with URI
>   [/Competitor-X-Ref-WS-SearchResults/http:/localhost:8080/Competitor-X-Ref-SearchResults/views/cross_reference_timeout.jsp]
>   in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'

following is some part of my web.xml :

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>0</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
<filter>
        <filter-name>SessionTimeOutFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.compxref.security.CompXrefSessionTimeOutFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>mode</param-name>
            <param-value>DENY</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>SessionTimeOutFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
<session-config>
        <session-timeout>60</session-timeout>
    </session-config>
```

Answer (score -1):

change url pattern from /* to *.do  it will work

Comment: for which one.. filter or dispatcher?

Comment: try both because you are applying filter to all incoming request.

Comment: I changed the dispatcher url pattern to *.do but unfortunately it didn't work.

Comment: make changes to controllers/filters accordingly it will work as the exception says it is unable to map to url you are providing

Comment: I tried changing the dispatcher URL to *.do and accordingly made changes to the controllers.Also changed URL pattern for filter in web.xml . But still it is not navigating to the required URL instead remain on same url that was previously open. Server logs shows -------org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/Competitor-X-Ref-WS-SearchResults/http:/localhost:8080/Competitor-X-Ref-SearchResults/views/cross_reference_timeout.jsp] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'

Comment: remove http:/localhost:8080/Com‌​petitor-X-Ref-Search‌​Results/ from URL in else part and keep only "cross_reference_timeout.jsp" check for view resolver settings as                                                                                    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
     <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/"/>
     <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </bean>                 in dispatcher-servlet.xml

Comment: Just want to bring to your notice that jsps and controllers/filters are in different wars